# Uploaded images not saved and displayed in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm working on user profiles, where the user can upload jpg images as their profile pictures. But the uploaded images are neither being stored in my media directory nor is it being displayed in the server. IT keeps displaying 'default photo' instead. I have set up the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in my settings file and have also added to the urls file, it's still not working. I'm new to Django, any help would be appreciated.

Here's my models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'


def save(self):
    super().save()

    image=Image.open(self.image.path)

    if image.height >300 or image.width  > 300:
        output_size=(300,300)
        image.thumbnail(output_size)
        image.save(self.image.path)
```

views.py:

```
def profile(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    update_form=UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    profile_form=ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES ,instance=request.user)
    if update_form .is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        update_form.save()
        profile_form.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!!')
        return redirect('profile')
else:
    update_form=UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
    profile_form=ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
context={
    'update_form': update_form,
    'profile_form':profile_form,
}
return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

profile.html:

```
<div class="card" id="profile" style="width: 18rem;">
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" alt="Default photo">
<div class="card-body">
    <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
    <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"><h1>Profile Info</h1></legend>
            {{ update_form|crispy }}
            {{ profile_form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-oultline-info" type="submit"> Update </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: show you settings for `MEDIA`

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi added it to the post

Comment: where is you media folder in project tree?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi right under the project directory, along with db and manage.py

Comment: show image of directory tree. Try my answer

Comment: Your code is missing `else` after validation check. Add it and return the validation errors to the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Create image filed in model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='account_image/', blank=True, null=True)
```

'GET' data by request

```
def profile(request):
    data = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', locals())
```

load in html

```
<img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="/media/{{user.profile.image}}">
```